# How to keep current view position after filtering pattern in vim

Tags: vim, text, filter

Want to view the most adjacent content after filtering pattern,is there a way to let vim show that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ``` `` ``` command to go back to the last position (if that is still valid).

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides a `:KeepView` command with which you can prefix your filter command.

Comment: Doesn't work since I use :g/pattern to show filtered text,command `` can't be used

Comment: I mostly answered the question in your title. For me that also works with `:g`. Else, try the `:KeepView`.

Comment: Oh, and is there another hidden question in the body, of showing additional context lines with `:g`?! Please don't ask multiple questions at once, it's confusing!

Comment: No hidden question here regarding to context line. The command KeepView actually doesn't work as it always displays from start when I use command like :KeepView g/test

Comment: Well, I guess then I misunderstood your terse question. So you want to list _all_ matches with `:g/test`, and then have the cursor placed on the _first_ match?